# how do i get back my missing styles.xml file in flutter

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, flutter, computer-vision

hello I'm currently going around in a circle .. so I'm building a project in android studio  using Flutter
but I have noticed the styles.xml folder under values is missing and I dont know how to get it back,
I've tried restarting the program any suggestions

Comment: what does this have to do with the computer vision tag? or with windows, for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't done any editing in your style file before, you can reach the easiest solution by creating a new project and pasting the values in it.